# RabbitTemplate Error: The ApplicationContext is closed and the ConnectionFactory can no longer create connections

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm using `Springboot 1.5.3` and `amqp-client 4.0.2`.

I have a producer that works fine most of the time, but once in a while I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ApplicationContext is closed and the ConnectionFactory can no longer create connections.
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:561) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:712) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:813) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:803) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]  
    at com.my.amqp.producer.MyProducer.produce(MyProducer.java:16) ~[classes!/:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

Here's the class that calls RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend from the produce(...) method:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

public class MyProducer {
    @Value("${rabbit.exchange.in.name}")
    public String exchangeNameIn;

    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public void produce(String messageToBeDelivered, String routingKey, int messageDelay) throws Exception {
        if (messageDelay > 0) {
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchangeNameIn, routingKey, messageToBeDelivered,
                m -> {
                    m.getMessageProperties().setCorrelationId("test-id".getBytes());
                    m.getMessageProperties().setHeader("x-delay", messageDelay);
                    return m;
                });
        } else {
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchangeNameIn, routingKey, messageToBeDelivered,
                m -> {
                    m.getMessageProperties().setCorrelationId("test-id".getBytes());
                    return m;
                });
        }
    }
}
```

The properties associated with rabbitmq:

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.concurrency=5
spring.rabbitmq.listener.max-concurrency=5
```

Answer (score 1):

Boot 1.5.x has not been supported for years.

Even Spring AMQP 1.7.x (and spring framework 4.x) is no longer supported.

See [here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp#learn) for supported versions.

That said, the error simply means your application is trying to reconnect to RabbitMQ after the application context has been shut down.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the reply.
Could you please break this down for me? 
How can the application context be closed if the Application is still up and trying to connect to RabbitMQ? I never explicitly close the ApplicationContext.

Comment: Something must be stopping it; that error is only emitted after we received the context closed event: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/e3f332a20519b75e8f1b9614ab58336b32c87fe9/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.java#L406-L411 Perhaps it's boot's shutdown hook and some code that is not managed by Spring is using the connection factory.

Comment: Hi, do you find how to fix this error ? I'm facing the same issue. Thank you

Comment: Provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits this behavior.